# Why does Java not find the directory?

Tags: java, file, directory

I have the following code:

```
File dir = Paths.get(new URI(url)).toFile();
System.out.println("Path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
if (!dir.exists())
{
// make new directory
}
```

The path that is printed out is "\\c\data\test".
This directory exists on my computer, but the compiler always tries to make a new directory.

Comment: But why would you introduce a `URI`? as opposed to `if (!Files.exists(Path.of(foo)))` And what's the value of `url`?

Comment: `url` has the value of `file://c:/data/test/`
I need `dir` later on in the code.

Comment: Have you tried to use `java.nio` exclusively? You can try `Path dir = Paths.get("c:/data/test/");` and then check for existence with `Files.exists(dir)`.

Comment: I think it's a little strange to be using a `URI` there (especially since it's a directory) but `"file:/c:/data/test/"` will suffice. More precisely, you want `Path p = Path.of(foo);if (!(Files.exists(p) && Files.isDirectory(p)))`

Comment: try with `url = "file:///c:/data/test/"` (Example of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) of URI: "`file:///~/calendar`" , or result of `Path.of("c:/data/test/").toUri()`)

Comment: The single slash works just as well

Answer (score 0):

Your URI is wrong.

There must be either one slash, or three slashes, after the scheme.  (The scheme is the `file:` part.)

Two slashes after the scheme means something very different.  Two slashes introduces an [authority](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) in a URI.  An authority is usually a hostname, optionally preceded by user and password, and optionally followed by a port number.

Obviously an authority makes no sense with a `file:` URI.  So two slashes is always incorrect in such a URI.

If the scheme is followed by only one slash, that means the authority is not present at all, and the scheme is immediately followed by a URI path, which is what you want.  (URI paths [always begin with a slash](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).)

If the scheme is followed by three slashes, that indicates an authority which has no information:  no user, no password, no hostname, no port.  That is perfectly acceptable with a `file:` URI, though it’s unnecessary.  The third slash is the start of the URI path that follows the empty authority;  it is not part of the authority itself.